# android studio 2.2 application: getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) crash

Tags: android

Android Studio 2.2 application 15-23:
**getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)**
crashes on **NOTE_5** **android 6.00 device**.  works fine on various number of other device types.  Any ideas?

Comment: Telephonymanager will work only on if sim exist in the device. otherwise it will return null.

Comment: Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE requires permission, and for 6.0 device you have to request Run Time  Permission. check out the following link: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Try this in 6.0 devices to request permision at runtime
    
private static final int APP_PERMISSION = 2;  

String[] PERMISSIONS={Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE};
       ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, APP_PERMISSION);

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have this in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

and that you are reqeuesting the permission at runtime. Check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) out for more information.